# Cannot complete the first Xamarin tutorial due to error: Package System.Numerics.Vectors 4.5.0 Not Compatible with netstandard2.0

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am very new to programming but I am very technical with computers. I have run into an issue with the first tutorial of Xamarin where you create an 'AwesomeApp' and just run it on a basic android emulator.

[Here are the 2 error messages I'm getting. I assume the issue is coming from the second one.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qs7k9.jpg)

The message reads:

NU1202 Package System.Numerics.Vectors 4.5.0 is not compatible with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). Package System.Numerics.Vectors 4.5.0 supports:

- monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
- monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
- netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0)
- uap10.0.16299 (UAP,Version=v10.0.16299)
- xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
- xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
- xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
- xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0) AwesomeApp C:\Users\jayce\source\repos\AwesomeApp\AwesomeApp\AwesomeApp\AwesomeApp.csproj 1

[Also, this is what shows with the System.Numerics.Vectors list in the solutions tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XO3aO.jpg)

I'm unsure of what to do at this point as I've searched the internet for an answer and nothing has seemed to work. I've tried reinstalling VS twice and using the 2017 version, but nothing has worked.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code or error messages. Include them directly in your question. If the links break you question will be useless for other people. Can you create an empty project using visual studio and does this compile without errors. I don't see why you would need the System.Numerics.Vectors package to begin with

Comment: there are thousands of Xamarin tutorials available from MS and elsewhere - we have no idea which one you are following

Comment: Hi Mouse on Mars - I am using a an empty project using Xamarin.Forms with a blank template. I am very new to programming and I don't understand what Systems.Numerics.Vectors even means.

Comment: Hi Jason,
Originally I was using this tutorial: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/xamarin/hello-world-tutorial/intro